# No update of db with POST using Retrofit 2, REST API and MongoDB

Tags: android, mongodb, rest, mongoose, retrofit

I need a simple POST method going from my android app using Retrofit, trough my REST-api build on Node, Express and mongoose and ending up in my Mongolab hosted db. The problem is I don't get any errors... Not from retrofit nor from my backend. But nothing gets added to my db. I want to add a 'user' which is defined as a POJO in my project. Both my getall and findbyid methods work fine, so I must be doing something wrong with my posting... Any help would be appreciated! :)

User POJO:

```
public class User {
@SerializedName("_id")
@Expose
private String id;
@SerializedName("emailaddress")
@Expose
private String emailaddress;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("lastName")
@Expose
private String lastName;
@SerializedName("password")
@Expose
private String password;
@SerializedName("vegetarianExperience")
@Expose
private Integer vegetarianExperience;
@SerializedName("familySituation")
@Expose
private Integer familySituation;
@SerializedName("newsletter")
@Expose
private boolean newsletter;
@SerializedName("score")
@Expose
private int score;
@SerializedName("challenges")
@Expose
private List<String> challenges = new ArrayList<>();
@SerializedName("favoriteRecipes")
@Expose
private List<String> favoriteRecipes = new ArrayList<>();

public User(String id, String emailaddress, String name, String lastName,
            String password, Integer vegetarianExperience, Integer familySituation,
            boolean newsletter, int score, List<String> challenges, List<String> favoriteRecipes) {
    this.id = id;
    this.emailaddress = emailaddress;
    this.name = name;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.password = password;
    this.vegetarianExperience = vegetarianExperience;
    this.familySituation = familySituation;
    this.newsletter = newsletter;
    this.score = score;
    this.challenges = challenges;
    this.favoriteRecipes = favoriteRecipes;
}

/*getters and setters*/

}
```

Usermodel in backend with mongoose:

```
var mongoose    = require('mongoose');
var Schema      = mongoose.Schema;
var ObjectId    = Schema.ObjectId;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
_id: ObjectId,
emailaddress: String,
name: String,
lastName: String,
password: String,
vegetarianExperience: Number,
familySituation: Number,
newsletter: Boolean,
score: Number,
challenges: [
    {
        type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Challenge'
    }
],
favoriteRecipes: [
    {
        type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Recipe'
    }
]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

My Client class in Java:

```
public class RestClient {

private static ApiInterface apiInterface;
private static String baseUrl = "http://188.166.128.173:8080/api/" ;

public static ApiInterface getClient() {
    if (apiInterface == null) {

        OkHttpClient okClient = new OkHttpClient();
        okClient.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());
                return response;
            }
        });

        Retrofit client = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .client(okClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        apiInterface = client.create(ApiInterface.class);
    }
    return apiInterface;
}

public interface ApiInterface {

    @GET("recipes")
    Call<List<Recipe>> recipes();

    @GET("users")
    Call<List<User>> userByMail(@Query("emailaddress") String emailaddress);

    @POST("users")
    Call<User> registerNewUser(@Body User user);
}
}
```

User created with the inputfields from my app and method that calls the api:

```
 private void registerNewUser(User user) {
    RestClient.ApiInterface service = RestClient.getClient();
    Call<User> registerNewUser = service.registerNewUser(user);
    registerNewUser.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<User> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
            if (response.isSuccess()) {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "User is gemaakt!!" + response.body());
                goToChallengeBoard();
            } else {
                Log.d("Error: ",  response.errorBody().toString());
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "GOE KAPOT " + t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

My app.js in backend:

```
var User     = require('./app/models/user');

router.route('/users')

// create a user (accessed at POST http://localhost:8080/api/users)
.post(function(req, res) {

    var user = new User(req.body);      // create a new instance of the User model

    // save the user and check for errors
    user.save(function(err) {
        if (err){
            return res.send(err);
        }

        res.json({ message: 'User created!' });
    });
})

// get all the users (accessed at GET http://localhost:8080/api/users)
.get(function(req, res) {
    User.find(function(err, users) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        res.json(users);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found the solution! The problem was that I was giving null as objectID in my constructor of the User object. I thought this wasn't a problem, because mongolab creates it's own id when adding a document to your collection. So I thought it would generate one aswell when coming from an API.

This wasn't the case so I needed mongoose to generate the id. 
It needed to edit the line where the _id is assigned:

```
var User     = require('./app/models/user');

router.route('/users')

// create a user (accessed at POST http://localhost:8080/api/users)
.post(function(req, res) {

  var user = new User();   //Not adding the req.body in the constructor

  user._id = mongoose.Type.ObjectId(); //<-------THIS IS THE SOLUTION

  //rest of attributes

  // save the user and check for errors
  user.save(function(err) {
      if (err){
          return res.send(err);
      }

      res.json({ message: 'User created!' });
  });
})

// get all the users (accessed at GET http://localhost:8080/api/users)
.get(function(req, res) {
  User.find(function(err, users) {
      if (err)
          res.send(err);

      res.json(users);
  });
});
```